# Ayuda con Node.Js

Tags: nodejs, http

Me encuentro realizando un mini servidor web en [Node.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs) con el fin de enviar notificaciones push a dispositivos móviles.

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
var apn = require('apn');

// Set up apn with the APNs Auth Key
var apnProvider = new apn.Provider({  
 token: {
    key: 'apns.p8', // Path to the key p8 file
    keyId: 'ABCDE12345', // The Key ID of the p8 file (available at https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/key)
    teamId: 'ABCDE12345', // The Team ID of your Apple Developer Account (available at https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/)
},
production: false // Set to true if sending a notification to a production iOS app
});

// Enter the device token from the Xcode console
var deviceToken = '5311839E985FA01B56E7AD74444C0157F7F71A2745D0FB50DED665E0E882';

// Prepare a new notification
var notification = new apn.Notification();

// Specify your iOS app's Bundle ID (accessible within the project editor)
notification.topic = 'my.bundle.id';

// Set expiration to 1 hour from now (in case device is offline)
notification.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600;

// Set app badge indicator
notification.badge = 3;

// Play ping.aiff sound when the notification is received
notification.sound = 'ping.aiff';

// Display the following message (the actual notification text, supports emoji)
notification.alert = 'Hello World \u270C';

// Send any extra payload data with the notification which will be accessible to your app in didReceiveRemoteNotification
notification.payload = {id: 123};

// Actually send the notification
apnProvider.send(notification, deviceToken).then(function(result) {  
// Check the result for any failed devices
console.log(result);
});
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para generar una función mediante la cual dispositivos móviles se puedan conectar con este servidor y enviar la variable `deviceToken` con el fin de no tener que introducir el token manualmente sino que sea automático?

¡Saludos!

Comment: podrias armarlo con express, y crear una ruta POST http://expressjs.com/es/guide/routing.html

Comment: ¿Los móviles enviarían su token al servidor para que éste envíe notificaciones, o los móviles **pedirían** el token al servidor?

Comment: Los móviles enviarían su token al servidor para éste envíe notificaciones.

Finalmente lo resolvi usando express con una ruta post, mediante la cual se envía el token del dispositivo y el servidor entrega las notificaciones correspondientes.

Pero me entraron dos dudas, 

1) Si el servidor recibe muchas peticiones post simultáneamente, generara todas las solicitudes o se podrían llegar a perder algunas?.

2) Existe algún riesgo de seguridad? El servidor no se conecta con ninguna base de datos y no existe la función get, por lo tanto no rescata información de la base de datos.

Comment: Si es una API privada obviamenre deberás autenticar. Respecto a tu otra duda,  siempre se manejarán todas las conexiones entrantes, aunque la cantidas de peticiones / segundo siempre va a ser determinado por el hardware y la optimización del servidor. Para aplicaciones de alto tráfico es mejor usar Koa que Express. Yo lo uso en un sistema que estoy desarollando para atender +10k peticiones x minuto y responde muy bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer para generar una función mediante la cual dispositivos móviles se puedan conectar con este servidor y enviar la variable `deviceToken`?

Creando un servidor HTTP para que los clientes puedan realizar peticiones. Hay muchas formas de hacerlo en [Node.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs). Puedes usar el módulo [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) de Node.js o usando algún framework como [Express](http://expressjs.com), [Koa](http://koajs.com/), etc.

**Usando** [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

```
const http = require('http');


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.method.toLowerCase() === 'get') {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.end(deviceToken); // envias el token en cada petición
  }
});
```

**Usando** [`Express`](http://www.expressjs.com/)

```
const express = require('express');


let app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.type('text/plain');
  res.send(deviceToken);
});
```

**Usando** [`Koa`](http://koajs.com/)

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const KoaRouter = require('koa-router');


let app = new Koa();
let router = new KoaRouter();

router.get('/', async (ctx) => {
  ctx.body = deviceToken;
});

app.use(router.routes());
```

---

**Nota:** ten en cuenta que esto no es seguro ya que cualquiera que conozca la dirección podrá hacer una petición y obtener el token. Debes implementar autenticación.